# Error: Compilation failed. Dart function failure

Tags: dart

```
void main(){
  int step1Result = add(n1= 5, n2= 9);
  int step2Result = multiply(step1Result,5);
  double finalResult = step2Result/3;
  print(finalResult);
}
​
int add(int n1, int n2) {
  return n1+n2;
}

int multiply(step1Result, multiplier) {
  return step1Result*multiplier;
}
```

Error:

```
Error compiling to JavaScript:
Warning: Interpreting this as package URI, 'package:dartpad_sample/main.dart'.
lib/main.dart:2:25:
Error: Setter not found: 'n1'.
  int step1Result = add(n1= 5, n2= 9);
                        ^^
lib/main.dart:2:32:
Error: Setter not found: 'n2'.
  int step1Result = add(n1= 5, n2= 9);
                               ^^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

I just don't get it, the syntax should be correct. I have tried also n1:5, n2:9 but still the same. Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `add` takes two positional arguments and not named arguments:

```
int add(int n1, int n2){
```

So you should call the method like this:

```
int step1Result = add(5, 9);
```

If you want to use named arguments you should encapsulate the arguments with `{ }` like this:

```
int add({int n1, int n2}){
```

This will make the two arguments optional which can be a problem with null-safety since the default value of `n1` and `n2` will be `null` which is not allowed for the datatype `int`. So you can either use `int?` or make the arguments required with the `required` keyword:

```
int add({required int n1, required int n2}){
```

And you can then call it like this:

```
int step1Result = add(n1: 5, n2: 9);
```

You can read more about the different types of parameters and the use of them in the Dart language tour: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. What do you recommend for the best practice then? It is kind of frustrating compared to Python when defining the variables. if one function has many inputs, it is better to use named arguments, and do we have to use 'required' every time?

Comment: @ZKK I know this is a very vague answer but... it depends. If your method takes a few arguments and the name of the method makes the arguments obvious, it can be simpler to just take positional arguments. But if you have more arguments, and where it can be confusing what each argument does, it can make the code more readable to have named arguments. It is mostly about code style and what you see as readable code.